# How to display an skeletal animation in WebGL on web browser

Tags: animation, three.js, webgl

I want to load and display this animation model in WebGL on web browser.

[blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoamrp2peo80jeg/foldtwiceAnim.blend)

[image: foldTwiceAnimation]

I exported a JSON file as skeletal animation with [an addon for three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender), and loaded it in WebGL, but it wasn't success.
I uploaded my [three.js code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e37pd73a7pmgdhc/skeletalTest.zip)

I referenced [this cite](http://devmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/creating-skeletal-animation-in-blender-and-exporting-it-to-three-js/), but I couldn't understand well.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I think I can help more if you can [upload](http://www.pasteall.org/blend) a simple scene, as well as an JSON file exported by yourself, in order to analyse what's going wrong.

Comment: See this BlenderArtists thread: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?333214-Blend4Web-a-3D-web-framework-for-Blender-artists&p=2644869&viewfull=1#post2644869 ![Cat jumping in my browser :)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8oja5.jpg) Powered by [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the experimental feature for exporting morph/skeletal animation when using that addon. I think that's the key.

[image]

Comment: In the blog post it is stated that "... the following options must be enabled: *skinning*, *bones* and *skeletal animation*." But I can think of other possible causes, like no action selected for the object, or maybe it's required to make the object selected/active? Or it's on the three.js side, maybe wrong code to use the anim?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But I selected this check, so I think three.js code is wrong. When a browser opened, it was  black. I'm searching an easy example of three.js code for skeletal animation.

Comment: @Momoko, I don't see a light source in your screenshot. Could that be why it is black?